# How implement a connection that manages connection?

Tags: java, singleton, database-connection, static-methods

Suppose to have this action:

```
Client-->Connection Handles-->(<--)connection poll
```

Connection pool is just create and the Connection Hanldes takes only the connection object.
My question is: which is the best way to implement Connection Handles?

1) Singleton

```
private static SingletonConnection s = null;

private SingletonConnection() {}

public static SingletonConnection getInstance() {
 if (s != null) {
  return s;
 } else {
  s = new SingletonConnection();
  return s;
 }
}
public Connection getStartConnection() {
 InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) initialContext
                .lookup("jdbc/mysqldb");
        java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
}
```

2)Static method
public static Connection getStartConnection(){

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) initialContext
                .lookup("jdbc/mysqldb");
        java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        return conn;
```

}

3) normal class `MyOperation m=new MyOperation();`

```
public class MyOperation(){

    private Connection connection;
    public MyOperation(){

    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) initialContext
                    .lookup("jdbc/mysqldb");
            java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
           connection=conn;
    }
}
```

which is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

If the handles' only use is to transfer connection references without context, I would recommend using a static method for simplicity. But if context can become important, singleton utility classes can be useful.